# AngularJS directive not being updated with parent scope variable changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive and a controller in my AngularJS app as shown below, where I need the directive to be updated with the controller scope variable changes.

Problem I am facing is that any change to the controller scope variable do not update the directive. I've tried using {scope: false}, tried making an isolated scope and one-way binding with the controller scope variable as shown below but none worked, so can someone please check my code and let me know what I am missing / doing wrong here? Thanks

1. First trial using isolated scope in directive

   ```
   .directive('loginPanelDir', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
          loginStatus: "&userLoginStatus"
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {            

           console.log(scope.loginStatus()); //will always print 0 despite of changes to the scope var in controller            
       }

    };
   });

   .controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $location) {       
       $scope.LoginStatus = "0";

       $scope.clickMe = function(){
          $scope.LoginStatus = "1";
       };

   });

   <div id="login" login-panel-dir user-login-status="LoginStatus">
   <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" ng-click="clickMe()">Login</button>
   ```
2. Second trial using {scope:false} in directive

   ```
   .directive('loginPanelDir', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: false,
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {            

           console.log(scope.LoginStatus()); //will always print 0 despite of changes to the scope var in controller         

       scope.$watch(function(){ scope.LoginStatus }, function(){
           console.log('Login status  : '+scope.LoginStatus);  //will always return 0...          
       });

       }

    };
   });

   .controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $location) {       
       $scope.LoginStatus = "0";
       $scope.clickMe = function(){
          $scope.LoginStatus = "1";
       };

   });

   <div id="login" login-panel-dir>
   <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" ng-click="clickMe()">Login</button>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `$timeouts` or `$intervals` to watch changes for certain scope values. Inside your directive you can watch for the changes of your login status via watching the `user-login-status` attribute.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OicaHhh5KgFpZNlkCSxT?p=preview)**

Something like this:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .controller('LoginController', function($scope) {
    $scope.LoginStatus = "0";

    $scope.clickMe = function(){
       $scope.LoginStatus = "1";
    };
  })

  .directive('loginPanelDir', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.userLoginStatus, function(value) {
        console.log(value);
      });
    }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="login" login-panel-dir user-login-status="LoginStatus">
  <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" ng-click="clickMe()">Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SAFlBx6vMnnvqtB2iMfb?p=info).
Use `$timeout` not `setTimeout`:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
       $scope.LoginStatus = "1";
    }, 3000);
```

should be:

```
 $timeout(function(){
       $scope.LoginStatus = "1";
    }, 3000);
```

`setTimeout` is native Javascript, so it will not run a digest and angular won't be notified of the changes hence no updates to the bindings, `$timeout` runs a digest when it completes, forcing an update to the binding.

Well [its working here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SAFlBx6vMnnvqtB2iMfb?p=info), just realized your `$watch` is also wrong:
it should be:

```
scope.$watch("LoginStatus", function(){
    console.log('Login status  : '+scope.LoginStatus);  //will always return 0...          
});
```

Comment: I am using & as I am doing one way binding. The issue is not related to timeout at all, even if I change the variable in any way it will still not update the directive

Comment: Once again it is not related to setTimeout. Even if I totally removed setTimeout and tried to change the variable in controller upon button click or so, it will not update the directive

Comment: Did you try my other suggestions regarding the way you pass it to the directive?

Comment: Please read the question update first. Yes I have tried all what you have suggested and I can assure you it doesn't work

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand is correct in regards to using `$timeout`.  Regardless of whether you instance of `setTimeout` works you should get in the habit of using angular options if they are available.  Eventually it will catch up with you because angular compiles and stores everything independently.